# Laravel - Request slug = channel_name in lower case

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I made a form which inserts new channels in the database and the slug equals the name of the channel but lowercase and without spaces. How can I achieve that in my code? This the controller it is going through:

```
 public function makeChannel(Request $request, Channel $channel) {
    $channel->channel_name = $request->channel_name;
    $channel->slug = $request->channel_name;
    $channel->save();

    return back()->with('flash', 'Het kanaal is aangemaakt');
}
```

The code works fine there are no problems but in the code above the slug just equals the channel_name. But can I achieve the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [slug helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-str-slug) built in Laravel like so:

```
$channel->slug = str_slug($request->channel_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $request->channel_name));
```