# channel vs channel_name - Laravel Echo and Laravel variable name for private channel

Tags: laravel, websocket, redis, nuxt.js, laravel-echo

I came across a weird thing while using Laravel Echo Server in NuxtJs, Redis, and Laravel 8.

Laravel Echo in NuxJs sends a WS message that looks like this:

`42["subscribe",{"channel":"container-details-3","auth":{"headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer ****"}}}]`

I am using API auth like this:

`Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]);`

This is failing because the request that comes through to my private channel auth in Laravel has a `channel` variable in it so `$request->channel` but Laravel is expecting `$request->channel_name`

[image]

By the looks of it I probably can't change it in Laravel since it is just hardcoded so my options are:

1. Change it in the middleware (seems like a nasty idea)
2. Force Laravel echo to change the payload of WS message so it will say `channel_name` instead of `channel`

Did anyone come across this issue before and what do you think would be the best thing to do here? Or I am completely lost here and just dead wrong?

All of that works fine when I hit auth endpoint via postman with the `channel_name` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I will be surprised if you are not able to edit the variable name in Laravel. I never did used this framework but this answer looks decent: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47518820/8816585

```
$channel->slug = str_slug($request->channel_name);
```

But yeah, rather change it on Laravel's side.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I see what you mean but this is not what I am after here I'm afraid. I can capture the request and change it. What bothers me is that the code from the screenshot comes from Laravel so Laravel expects `channel_name` while Laravel Echo Library sends off `channel` variable in the message. The two don't match and since `channel_name` is hardcoded in Laravel's code it seems to me like I would have to override the frontend bit. This is really weird situation. Makes me think I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: But then again I am probably missing something important here. I am trying to find a solution where I don't end up with weird workarounds.